# Keyboard Shortcut interface-like

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts, interface

How can I create a similar interface like this but for custom shortcuts?

For VImproved for example, I would like to be in VIM and be able to press a key for a few seconds to have it appear with a cheatsheet of vim key combinations

Comment: When you mention *like this*, did you want to insert any images or something else to show us what are you trying to create?

Comment: Press and hold the windows/command key, that's what I mean by "this", the default Ubuntu Keyboard Shortcut interface.